# Is Twitter site only in English?

Tags: twitter, localization

Is Twitter site only in English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in Japanese also: http://blog.twitter.com/2009/10/coming-soon-twitter-in-more-languages.html

Actually, you can choose between Italian, Spanish, French, German and Japanese:

[image: Twitter language selector]

Comment: I can change the language in http://twitter.com/settings/account